# Including child entity ADO.net EF, LinqToEntities

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-entities, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm trying to get all my child entities to get loaded in the same query as the "master" table, instead of every property loads one by one.

It's an ADO.net database model connected to SQL Server 2008.

The application is a LightSwitch app that uses and LinqToEntites Domain Service.

My master table metadata, where "Country" is the foreign key:

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(RuleEntry.RuleEntryMetadata))]
public partial class RuleEntry
{
    internal sealed class RuleEntryMetadata
    {
        private RuleEntryMetadata()
        {
        }

        .....


        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Include]
        [Association("RuleEntry_Country", "Country", "Code", IsForeignKey=true)]
        public Country Country1 { get; set; }

        .....
        }
    }
}
```

Country metadata:

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(Country.CountryMetadata))]
public partial class Country
{
    internal sealed class CountryMetadata
    {
        private CountryMetadata()
        {
        }

        [Key]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Association("RuleEntry_Country", "Code", "Country", IsForeignKey = false)]
        public EntityCollection<RuleEntry> RuleEntries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the call in the Domain Service:

```
[Query(IsDefault = true)]
    public IQueryable<RuleEntry> GetRuleEntries()
    {
        var query = this.ObjectContext.RuleEntries.Include("Country1");
        return query;
    }
```

This gives no errors, but still the Country entity wont be included in the query and thus being loaded one time for each row, which takes very long timd.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the SQL that's sent to the database?

Comment: @GertArnold I don't know where to see the pure SQL but here's a shot of how the service calls looks like, http://snag.gy/JKqEO.jpg, where the master table is loaded first and then all the related entities one by one.